# Arguments not working in cartoDB createLayer method

Tags: javascript, carto, carto-js

I added a cartoDB layer to an existing map using `createLayer` method and it loaded properly. Thereafter, created a variable `params` and parsed the arguments as sees on the code snippet below. Unfortunately I am not able to see the title, shareable button and the search bar on my map. What could be wrong?

```
var params = {
  search: true,
  cartodb_logo: false,
  mobile_layout: true,
  shareable: true,
  title: true
}

cartodb.createLayer(map, jsonUrl, params).addTo(map)
.on('done', function(layer){
  layer.setZIndex(1000); baseLayer
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things wrong in your code. First of all, you should use `createVis` instead of `createLayer` in order to set map options. Then, you have to use as function arguments `vis` and `layer`/s if you want to set interactions. [Here](http://bl.ocks.org/ramiroaznar/cf23c61ddbf8be930208ad664fc158bb) I have built a working example using createVis with map options like the ones in your `params` object. :-)

Comment: Thanks @ramiroaznar, I thought one was able to set the map options on a base layer that is not provided by cartodb.

Comment: You can also customize your basemap options using createLayer with Leaflet: `var map = L.map('map', options);`.

Comment: It worked. Used the map options as documented here http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-options